# volatile multi-threading data inconsistency

Tags: java, multithreading, volatile

I thought I had taken the necessary steps to prevent data races but it seems it has not worked...

I've coded a hierarchical state machine to implement a coin quiz game.
One of my JUnit tests checks to see if the last line printed to screen is expected, given a credit event has just been processed.
I'm finding that the line does get printed on screen as expected, however the String used to store the last printed value is null at the point of test.

I've made sure that the String reference is `volatile`, so I'd expect the writes from the event processing thread to be visible to the reads on JUnit thread.

The machine class contains the event processing loop and the following code for reading and writing to the String reference:

```
private volatile String lastPrintln;

public String lastPrintln(){
    return lastPrintln;
}

void println(String s){
   System.out.println(s);
   lastPrintln = s;
}
```

The testing code is as follows...

```
@Before
public void setUp() throws Exception {
    machine = Objects.create(CoinQuizMachine.class);
    machine.start(); // starts event loop thread
}

private void waitForEventQueueToEmpty(){
    while(!machine.eventQueueIsEmpty()){

    }
}

private void processTestEvent(Event e){
    machine.add(e);
    waitForEventQueueToEmpty();
}

@Test
public void test2() {   
    assertEquals(Demo.class,machine.activeState().getClass());
    processTestEvent(new CreditEvent(1));
    assertEquals("Topic Choices: \nMaths\nScience",machine.lastPrintln());
}
```

Comment: I don't see where the `println(String)` method is called.  If the string is `null` then that method is not called before the call to `lastPrintln()`.  I'd put a break point in `println(String)`.

Comment: What's your JDK version? volatile behaves differently from 1.5.

Comment: println(String) gets called within the event loop and with a non-null value. I'm using 1.7

Comment: Please show the code where the `println(String)` is invoked and where you remove the event from the event queue.

Comment: Yep my bad, I found the bug, I was decreasing the value of unprocessed events before they had actually been processed, meaning that the test triggered to early, and at times when the lastPrintln had not been updated. Thanks for your help guys.

Answer (score 0):

Yep my bad, I found the bug, I was decreasing the value of unprocessed events before they had actually been processed, meaning that the test triggered to early, and at times when the lastPrintln had not been updated. Thanks for your help guys.